# how do I filter on integers in a list containing different data types in python

Tags: python, list, lambda, filter, list-comprehension

I have a list containing both integers and strings.

```
old_list = ['Hello', 'fox', 13, 10, 22, 5]
```

I'd like to filter the list to remove values that are less than or equal to 10

```
new_list = ['Hello', 'fox', 13, 22]
```

I'm trying to do this using either a list comprehension or ideally a filter. My initial attempt at this is below:

```
def filter(input):
    return [x for x in old_list if isinstance(x, int) and x <= 10
```

This results in an output of:

```
[13, 22]
```

Thanks for any guidance! I'm new to python and this is my first post, so apologies if there are issues with how I've made the submission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only trying to remove the integers that are equal or less than 10 and not modify the strings:

```
old_list = ['Hello', 'fox', 13, 10, 22, 5]  
new_list = [x for x in old_list if type(x) == str or x > 10]  
print(new_list)
```

If you only want integers that are more than 10 and nothing else:

```
old_list = ['Hello', 'fox', 13, 10, 22, 5]  
new_list = [x for x in old_list if type(x) == int and x > 10]  
print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

This adds all the values from the input that are not integers smaller than 10 to the result:

```
def filter(input):
  return [x for x in old_list if not (isinstance(x, int) and x <= 10)]
```

Comment: shouldn't it be ```if isinstance(x, int)``` and not ```if not...``` ?

Comment: The question asked to 'remove values that are less than or equal to 10'. Putting not makes it not add that value to the final list if there is a match.

Comment: Great stuff! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Python has a builtln function called `filter()`. It is not recommend you redefine it.Also,You could use it directly:

```
old_list = ['Hello', 'fox', 13, 10, 22, 5]
new_list = list(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, str) or x > 10,old_list)))
# ['Hello', 'fox', 13, 22]
```